# using PHP to recommend products based on the current view item

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wanted to know how to use PHP to show recommend items based on what the user is viewing or has in cart.

I have a view page in which I display all my items and when the user clicks on the item. The `ID` of the item is posted to the `product detail` page in which I render the product by using the `ID` to select from my `product table`

In my product I have `product table`

I have something like below with over 40 records. 10 of it are `shoes`

```
Id, name    category     desc

1   leather  shoe    blah 
2   italian  shoe    blah blah
```

In my `product detail` page. I want to echo some recommended items atleast 4 of the items item some divs with just an image and name.

**My question**

How can I select an item based on the category of the item getting view? for an example in my table, lets says i was viewing item 1 which is in the `category` columns. I want to show random 4 items in the `category` columns.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP or PDO. you're just fishing for an SQL query, and that query will remain the same no matter what language you're working with.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you asking for the SQL or how to display the results using PHP?

Comment: Agree with Azzi... nowhere near enough information provided in your question for us to provide a viable solution... or even know where to begin.

Comment: @Azzi i think the query is more of what I am looking for? how can i select from the category which relates to the item getting view?

Comment: You will have to develop some sort of ranking system that can rank attributes in order of importance to the likeness of the item in the cart.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus if i do that thats means that I am not going to show most of the items.

Comment: A quick google-oogling found this http://easyrec.org/ and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738603/poor-mans-product-recommendation-implementation

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your data set up as such.

items:

```
+----+-------------+------+
| id | category_id | name |
+----+-------------+------+
```

categories:

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
```

You could use

```
select *
from items
left join categories
  on categories.id = items.id
where item.category_id = $category_id
limit 4
```

this will pull 4 items from the same category as whatever $category_id is set to.

thats as good an answer as i can give with the data you've given.

Comment: thanks I think i found another way around this. The problem I had with this was that it even show the same item item in the list.